# Number Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, function, number-formatting

The Bloomberg Terminal has an interesting way of formatting numbers. I want to imitate this format in Excel, but have been struggling to get it to make it work.

**Examples of the formatting I want is:**

- 1,000,000 = 1MM
- 1,400,000 = 1400M
- 100,000 = 100M
- 75,000 = 75M
- 10,000,000 = 10MM
- 25,300,000 = 25,300MM

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A way to nearly achieve that result would be to use a formula such as `=TEXT(A1,"#,") & "M"` which will replace the last three zeros with a M...

Comment: @Xabier I have been able to format these with one of these formats, but is there a way to have it format to include both MM and M formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Here's one more solution that you can use (independent of the number of zeros):

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")))-MOD((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))),3))),"#,##")&REPT("M",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")))/3)
```

`LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))` part is counting how many times "0" is occurring in a given string.

The result looks like that:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the help! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're most welcome & thanks for an interesting challenge :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula that would handle up to 6 zeros. You could easily add a condition for more zeros at the beginning:

```
=IFS(RIGHT(A1,6)="000000",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)&"MM",RIGHT(A1,3)="000",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)&"M",TRUE,A1)
```

Results:
[image: Results in spreadsheet]